# Which algorithm browsers use to detect mouse over an element with rounded edges and rotation?

Tags: algorithm, web, math, overlap, sat

How elements with rounded edges (border-radius) or rotation are calculated along the mouse point? Is it SAT? How corner angles are defined?

Mouse point/pixel represented as "cursor"
[image]

Comment: I've never seen a rectangular mouse cursor before. The usually have a point on them.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Mouse point = a single pixel (square)

Comment: Both Chromium and Firefox are open source: rather than ask us, it's probably time to start reading some source code. And yeah: that's not trivial, but then neither is this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the SDF of a 2D box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62-pRVZuS5c&list=PL0EpikNmjs2AUFqRi3vmpkrO3j-zWuoyq&index=4) minus the radius of the rounded corners and as said in the video, transform the space to make the translation and the rotation. To know if the cursor is in the box, you can just check if the result is negative or not.